# Is there any way to right align image in UIAlertAction in UIAlertController action sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have managed to left align text but unable to set image to right in UIAlertAction

```
let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Text 1", style: .default, handler: { action in
            })
firstAction.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
firstAction.setValue(image, forKey: "image") // this puts image to left by default
```

I want to achieve this [To achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg4C7.png)

But so far I have this [Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcml4.png)

Comment: A little warning: You are using private API, so it make break anytime on new iOS release. I'd suggest you to use a custom sheet instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to customize the action sheet by adding a table view to it. This help to add other functionalities too.

Comment: The actionsheet already have a tableview on it.